# Why are the mountPaths of the 2 containers different while they are accessing the same volume?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm so confused by this concept. The author of the tutorial I'm watching said that these 2 containers have access to the same volume. Why are the mountPaths then different?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Kubernetes can't use the PNG file you've attached to the question.  Can you [edit] the question to include a plain-text YAML artifact?

Comment: @Richard77 ,Let me know if the below provided answer was helpful. I am happy to assist you in case of any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the **[blog](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/multi-container-pods-and-container-communication-in-kubernetes/)** written by **Nick Chase** and the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/#before-you-begin) available

**Multi-Container Pod With A Shared Volume:**

The main use of Kubernetes **multi-container Pod** with a **shared Volume** is one container **writes** logs or other files to the shared directory and the other container **reads** from the shared directory.

In Kubernetes, you can use a **shared Kubernetes Volume to share data between containers in a Pod**. Kubernetes Volumes enables data to survive **container restarts**, but these volumes have the same lifetime as the Pod. That means that the volume (and the data it holds) exists exactly as long as that Pod exists. If that Pod is deleted for any reason, even if an identical replacement is created, the shared Volume is also destroyed and created as new.

**Mount paths of shared volume:**

In your YAML file ,you have defined a **volume** with the name **html**. Its type is **emptyDir**, which means that the volume is first created when a Pod is assigned to a node, and exists as long as that Pod is running on that node.The first container runs **nginx server** and has the shared volume mounted to the directory **/usr/share/nginx/html**. The second container uses the **alpine image** and has the shared volume mounted to the directory **/html**. For every 10 seconds, the second container adds the current date and time into the index.html file, which is located in the shared volume. When there is an HTTP request to the Pod, the Nginx server reads this file and transfers it back to the user in response to the request.

Answer (score 2):

`mountPath` is the path inside the pod/container.

In your example, the `html` volume is mounted to both `nginx:/usr/share/nginx/html` and `html-updater:/html`